# Не добавляются данные в базу данных

Tags: java, android

При отправке данных на сервер ничего не происходит, и как следствие данные не добавляются в базу. Вот лог происходящего:

```
    07-22 17:21:20.088 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /77.87.193.68:80;LocalPort=42950(0)
07-22 17:21:20.088 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/77.87.193.68:80] tm:90
07-22 17:21:20.089 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process avdeewkiril.paybillet :80 
07-22 17:21:20.149 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.3:42950] connected
07-22 17:21:20.149 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
07-22 17:21:20.149 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet W/System.err: rto value is too small:0
07-22 17:21:20.152 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: >doSendRequest
07-22 17:21:20.152 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: <doSendRequest
07-22 17:21:20.213 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: [CDS]close[42950]
07-22 17:21:20.213 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:42950]
07-22 17:21:20.214 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:42950]
07-22 17:21:20.216 30102-30346/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/Create response: {"message":"Oops! An error occurred.","success":0}
07-22 17:21:20.217 30102-30102/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-22 17:21:20.248 30102-30352/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: interp stack at 0x5ebd2000
```

Насколько я понял ошибка происходит в строчке `W/System.err: rto value is too small:0`
Чем она может быть вызвана и что она означает? Данные посылаются из TextView'a в формате даты(00-00-0000). Прикрепляю код приложения и php скрипта.

```
   <?php
header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['real_date_from']) && isset($_POST['real_date_back']) && isset($_POST['pay_status'])) {

    $real_date_from = $_POST['real_date_from'];
    $real_date_back = $_POST['real_date_back'];
    $pay_status = $_POST['pay_status'];

    require 'db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'bus_order'(real_date_from, real_date_back, pay_status) VALUES('$real_date_from', '$real_date_back', '$pay_status')");

    if ($result) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Код приложения:

```
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_create_new_ticket = "http://kolumbplus.com/create_order.php";

    private static String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    class NewBillet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Бронирование биллета");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String[]args){
            String pay_status = "no";
            String real_date_from = args[0];
            String real_date_back = args[1];
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_from", real_date_from));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_back", real_date_back));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pay_status", pay_status));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_new_ticket, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create response", json.toString());
            try{
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tickets.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void Bronirovat(View v)
    {
        TextView real_date_from =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        TextView real_date_back = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
        new NewBillet().execute(real_date_from.getText().toString(), real_date_back.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

На всякий случай прикрепляю скриншот базы данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: причин может быть сотни. Например, вы указали в БД одно из полей, как NOT_NULL, и не заполняете его при инсерте. Попробуйте выполнить этот же запрос с этими же данными в MySQL-Workbench